# How to enable // in vscode which the shortcut key ctrl + / or ? button is not working on vscode any suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code

Usally while am coding the // to hide the code ctrl + / is not working on vscode so any have idea about it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default keybinding to comment out the highlighted code is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd>. Please note these are what Microsoft calls [chords](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

> Chords (two separate keypress actions) are described by separating the two keypresses with a space. For example, Ctrl+K Ctrl+C.

Comment: @joeshmo - bet he won't